# How to disable https in IdentityServer 3

Tags: c#, authentication, https, identityserver3, openid-connect

I need to use IdSrv3 with http instead of https because some of our clients want single sign on authentication without https. Is there any way to disable https?

Comment: I hope not. That would be an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Turning HTTPS off is useful for load balancing, testing etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set `RequireSsl = false` and started my selfhost console application on http://localhost:44333. All works. But not fully tested.

Comment: Where is that setting?